# Uploading SSRS report causes datasource to require credentials

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I currently have a report whose datasource requires no credentials

[image: Datasource doesn't require credentials]

I want to programatically upload this report to my Report Server, to do this, I'm using the `ReportingService2010` class and the following code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010_methods.aspx

```
Dim service As New ReportingService2010()
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials  
service.Url = _reportServerUrl & "/reportservice2010.asmx?"
service.CreateCatalogItem("Report", reportName, pathinServer, True,
                              fileBytes, Nothing, warnings)
```

This uploads the report, the problem is that the report's datasource configuration is not being preserved after it gets uploaded.

[image: Setting was changed from "Do not use credentials" to "Prompt for credentials"]

My question is why does this happen and what's a workaround for this? I couldn't find a way to programmatically change this setting.

Comment: There is an option to overwrite the datasource when deploying. You can also change it on the server or delete and redeploy

Comment: This is a first time deployment, nothing is being overriden

Comment: Actually, my current workaround is that I manually change this for all reports then it doesn't happen for the subsequent times, but then I get it again every time we get a new report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that credential settings can be changed with `SetItemDataSources` method.

```
Dim sources = service.GetItemDataSources(itemFullPath)

For Each dataSource In sources
    CType(dataSource.Item, DataSourceDefinition).CredentialRetrieval = CredentialRetrievalEnum.None
Next

service.SetItemDataSources(itemFullPath, sources)
```

When I first inspected the dataSource item I missed the fact that I had to cast it into a `DataSourceDefinition` to access the `CredentialRetrieval` property